# Restructure an Array list and output the list if they match based on key => value

Tags: php, foreach, associative-array

I have a data set which I am looping through using the foreach the results currently are showing as below;
Currently the output is like below:

- Monday : Closed
- Tuesday : 12:00 pm - 9:00 pm
- Wednesday : 12:00 pm - 2:00 pm
- Wednesday : 5:00 pm - 9:00 pm
- Thursday : 12:00 pm - 2:00 pm
- Thursday : 5:00 pm - 9:00 pm
- Friday : 12:00 pm - 9:00 pm
- Saturday : 12:00 pm - 9:00 pm
- Sunday : Closed

My objective is to combine same day in one as below which I am not sure how to go about it.

- Monday : Closed
- Tuesday : 12:00 pm - 9:00 pm
- Wednesday : 12:00 pm - 2:00 pm &  5:00 pm - 9:00 pm
- Thursday : 12:00 pm - 2:00 pm & 5:00 pm - 9:00 pm
- Friday : 12:00 pm - 9:00 pm
- Saturday : 12:00 pm - 9:00 pm
- Sunday : Closed

```html
<?php foreach( $opening_hours as $row ) : ?>
<?php $day_of_week = $row['day_of_week']; ?>
<?php $open_24hr = $row['open_24hr']; ?>
<?php $closed_24hr = $row['closed_24hr']; ?>
<?php $opens = $row['opens']; ?>
<?php $closes = $row['closes']; ?>
<div class="hours__row">
  <p>
    <span><?php echo $day_of_week; ?></span> :
    <?php if( $closed_24hr ) : ?>
    <span>Closed</span>
    <?php elseif( $open_24hr ) : ?>
    <span>Open</span>
    <?php elseif( !$opens && $closes ) : ?>
    <span>Closes at <?php echo $closes; ?></span>
    <?php elseif( $opens && !$closes ) : ?>
    <span>Open from <?php echo $opens; ?></span>
    <?php else: ?>
    <span><?php echo $opens; ?></span> - <span><?php echo $closes; ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </p>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

[How currently looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgcnP.png)

[What it needs to be.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCxbv.png)

Comment: Restructure your starting array `$opening_hours` so that the data is grouped by day. Then it's only a simple matter of checking whether you have multiple values for a given day and combining them if it's true.

Comment: Images should be embedded into the question. Check code indentation and text punctuation. [ask]